# libavcodec.a linker error when linking to FFmpeg from QtApp

Tags: xcode, qt, ffmpeg, linker-errors, codec

I am trying to link my **Qt app** to **FFmpeg**. I *built FFmpeg from source as static libraries* using a script from [here](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script). And, x264 from [here](https://github.com/kewlbear/x264-ios).

The build was ok. Following are the Configure flags I used for FFmpeg:

```
CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --enable-debug --disable-programs --enable-postproc \
              --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample \
              --disable-doc --enable-pic --enable-static --disable-opencl --disable-shared --disable-securetransport \
              --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-gpl"
```

Configure flags for x264:

```
CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--enable-static --enable-pic --disable-cli --disable-asm"
```

Following is how I link the libraries from my `QtApp` **trying to build it for MacOSX**:

```
LIBS+= -LPath/to/ffmpeg/build/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lswresample \ 
-lavdevice -lpostproc -lx264 -lz -llzma -lbz2 -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreMedia \ 
-framework VideoToolbox -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -framework CoreServices -framework AVFoundation \ 
-framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics
```

I am including `FFmpeg` headers as recommended as well:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
  #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
  #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
  #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
  #include <libavutil/frame.h>
}
#endif

#if LIBAVCODEC_VERSION_INT < AV_VERSION_INT(55,28,1)
#define av_frame_alloc  avcodec_alloc_frame
#endif
```

**Issue:**
But **when I call** `av_register_all`. I am getting the following linker errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_VDADecoderCreate", referenced from:
  _ff_vda_create_decoder in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
  _ff_vda_default_init in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
"_VDADecoderDecode", referenced from:
  _vda_old_h264_end_frame in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
  _vda_h264_end_frame in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
"_VDADecoderDestroy", referenced from:
  _ff_vda_destroy_decoder in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
"_VDADecoderFlush", referenced from:
  _vda_old_h264_end_frame in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
  _vda_h264_end_frame in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
"_kVDADecoderConfiguration_Height", referenced from:
  _ff_vda_create_decoder in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
  _ff_vda_default_init in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
"_kVDADecoderConfiguration_SourceFormat", referenced from:
  _ff_vda_create_decoder in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
  _ff_vda_default_init in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
"_kVDADecoderConfiguration_Width", referenced from:
  _ff_vda_create_decoder in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
  _ff_vda_default_init in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
"_kVDADecoderConfiguration_avcCData", referenced from:
  _ff_vda_create_decoder in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
  _ff_vda_default_init in libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Question:**
What am I missing here?

Comment: Edited the error log in the question. wasn't correct in the first draft of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed** it. Following is missing in the linker list

```
LIBS += -framework VideoDecodeAcceleration
```

That fixes all linker issues related to `libavcodec.a(vda_h264.o)`
Yep.